# Azure Databricks : Schema mismatch to load incremental xml data using com.databricks.spark.xml. (Convert struct to array)

Tags: pyspark, xml-parsing, azure-databricks

I want to load incremental XML data but for one field spark sometimes infers schema as struct when there is single row and array when there are two rows.

Single row example (Ship is inferred here as struct coulmn) :

Ships Ship ShipID 123 /ShipID /Ship /Ships

double row example (Ship is inferred here as array column) :

Ships Ship ShipID 123 /ShipID ShipID 234 /ShipID /Ship /Ships

Which is causing schema mismatch.

Can you help how to convert struct to array, or if you have any other solution

I tried casting but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Define the schema of XML data manually and then use that in dataframe.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val custom_schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("Ships", ArrayType(
    StructType(Seq(
      StructField("ShipID", StringType)
    ))
  ))
))

val df = spark.read
  .schema(custom_schema )
  .option("rootTag", "Ships")
  .option("rowTag", "Ship")
  .xml("dbfs:/***/shipfile1.xml")
```

This is tested with two cases. case1 is with single ShipId . case2 is with two shipIds.

**Input1**:

```xml
<Ships>
    <Ship>
        <ShipID>789</ShipID>
    </Ship>
</Ships>
```

**Output1**
| Ships   |
|---------|
| [[789]] |

**Input2:**

```xml
<Ships>
    <Ship>
        <ShipID>123</ShipID>
    </Ship>
    <Ship>
        <ShipID>234</ShipID>
    </Ship>
</Ships>
```

**Output2:**

| Ships |
| --- |
| [[123],[234]] |

Reference:  databricks [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/xml#scala) on XML file.

Comment: Thanks Aswin, but for the structure that we follow in our project we do not define schema manually as a fact  we do not define schema at all. Let me know if you have any other options.